# Transform ul list into a tabs while keeping the same appearance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'am using jquery ui tabs to create a single page app. I've constructed the page navigation layout. The last thing was to transform the navigation into tabs.

I am having difficulties shifting to tabbed layout, while keeping the same appearance of the page.

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nkxky48p/1/) with the setup. There is some css reset applied (you can ignore it), and under JS, there is

```
//        $("#pagewraper").tabs();
```

I was hoping I could just use the functionality of tabs, but keep the appearance I designed before addig tabs functionality. Can this be done? Am I better of writing my own tabbed functionality?

Comment: Can you share some of your HTML?

Comment: Sure, it is already in the question.

Comment: oops, my mistake - i see it now

Comment: What you could do is make sure your CSS is included *after* the stylesheet for jQuery UI, so that your styles override jQuery UI's. You can also add `!important` to your CSS rules (e.g. `color: red !important;` to prevent them from being overridden by jQuery UI. You may have to manually override any CSS properties that jQuery UI sets which you haven't explicitly set. You can check exactly what properties jQuery UI is setting by right clicking elements, and clicking "Inspect Element".

Comment: thanks, there are more than 50 styles I need to override:D better rollup my sleves

Comment: you know, maybe writing a simple custom tab solution would be easier in that case :P

Comment: I guess I was a little afraid of doing tabs on my own. It turned out to extremly easy:  https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.en.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad you managed to find a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom tab script. Here's how I would modify yours.

Add this to CSS:

```
#container div {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

#container div.tab-content-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

This will hide the tab content, and give them some padding so that they aren't pressed up against the border of the page. When one of the divs has the class "tab-content-visible", it will appear again.

Slight change to two places in your HTML. Here's the first:

```
<ul class="app-nav">
  <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="current-tab">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add the class current-tab to your first tab. This will make sense very soon.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content-visible">
    <p>Tab one content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab two content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab three content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Tab four content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add the class tab-content-visible to your first tab's data. These HTML and CSS edits so far hide tab data for every tab, except for the first tab. Thus, your first tab is now your "default" tab.

Finally, add the following to your javascript:

```
$(".app-nav li").click(function(e) {
  $(this).find("a").click();
});

$(".app-nav li a").click(function(e) {
  $(".current-tab").removeClass("current-tab");
  $(".tab-content-visible").removeClass("tab-content-visible");

  $(this).closest("li").addClass("current-tab").removeClass("app-nav-selected");

  var selector = $(this).attr("href");
  $(selector).addClass("tab-content-visible");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's how this works. If an LI is clicked, the anchor tag inside of it is found, and its onclick handler is triggered.

If a tab's anchor tag is clicked, first things first - the current tab is invalidated. We remove the current-tab class from the current tab, and the visible class from the visible tab data. Then, we add the current-tab class to the LI parent of this anchor (closest is a function that finds the nearest ancestor matching a selector), and add the class current-tab. Note that due to your hover handler, we will also have to remove "app-nav-selected" at this point, otherwise the toggle will be messed up. Review your hover handler to see why this is so.

Finally, the anchor tag's href is used to get a selector that can be used to find the tab data that we want to make visible. We add the visible class name to it, and we're done. Aside from a call to e.preventDefault(), which will prevent the link from actually taking the user anywhere. It'll also prevent the page from scrolling, which may cause the tabs to disappear from view. It wouldn't break the implementation since the user could just scroll up, but it certainly wouldn't look pretty.

Comment: Thanks mate! Just wanted to tell you that your approach is superior to the one with :target selector. :target causes scroll change, which in super annoying.

Comment: Thank you sir :) Again, I'm glad I could help.